# Disable trim in WordPress

Tags: functions

I have a post. That is that post:

```
- A
- B
- C
```

When I use function `the_excerpt()`, it changed:

```
- A
- B
readmore
```

I want it to have the old structure.

```
- A
- B
readmore
```

but I don't know I need can change where.

Mayeenul Islam: thank you very much. I did it. I don't understand when i read your comment in the first. But i read again and i see problem.

Comment: are you writing code for the theme or just trying to add content?

Answer (score 1):

Use `the_content()` instead.

WordPress Codex Reference:

- [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content)
- [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)

And till, if you want to enable the trim anywhere, wherever you want, manually try the **Insert More Tag** button in your Post editor:
[image: More Tag Insertion]